# How do I interpret the time series processes format?

Tags: time-series, random

How do I interpret the result:

`ARIMAProcess[2.22836, {0.363326}, 1, {}, 6.35083]`

in terms of the equivalent recurrence equation; say

`y[t] = 2.22836 + 0.363326y[t-1]`...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you can use `ARProcess` representation of `ARIMAProcess[2.22836, {0.363326}, 1, {}, 6.35083]`:

```
proc = ARIMAProcess[c, {a}, 1, {}, v];
arproc = ARProcess[proc, 5]
```

> ARProcess[c, {1 + a, -a}, v]

Using the general difference equation representation from  [ARProcess >> Details](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ARProcess.html)

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

we get, for `aproc`:

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

where `e(t)` is white noise with variance `v`.

Alternatively,

```
 y[t] = c + (1+a) y[t-1] - a y[t-2] + Sqrt[v] u[t]
```

where `u[t]` is white noise with variance `1`.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply ... prg

Comment: @PRG, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept. Welcome to mma.se.